# NLog logs Error twice in same file

Tags: nlog

I am trying to figure out why NLog logs my error twice.

here is my config file:

```
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="debug" xsi:type="File" FileName="DebugTestFile.log" layout="${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" level="Debug" writeTo="debug" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Now when I call `NLog.Debug(myException);` the output is my exception gets printed twice.

If I call `NLog.Debug(myException, "My Test Message String");` then the error gets printed out once along with my test message.

What exactly am I doing wrong?  According to https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-Log-Exceptions my configuration is correct.

I tried changing my layout to the following: `layout="${message}` and when I ran `NLog.Debug(myException);` it only printed the error once.

However now when I ran `NLog.Debug(myException, "My Test Message String");` it only printed my message without the error that comes from exception.

Could this be a bug with NLog?

Comment: This seems to be as designed.  You are passing a single argument (your exception) which is being used to satisfy both layout renderers.

Comment: @Joe But then, if I remove the error from config, I don't get the error printed out when I call the exception, string method.  That can't be right, there has to be something I am missing or a bug in the system.

Comment: @Bagzli Did you solve this problem?

Comment: no I have not, I went with a workaround where I call `NLog.Debug(myException, myMessage);` which doesn't do that, and my message is an empty string.

Answer (score 16):

**Updated Answer**

NLog.Web.AspNetCore v4.8.6 [changes registration of NLog Logging Provider](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/485), so one is now allowed to call both `AddNLog` and `UseNLog` without experiencing double logging.

NLog 5.0 implements [validation of incorrect duplicate target configuration](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/4354), so one will not experience double logging when using incorrect NLog configuration.

**Original Answer**

If you are using NLog in AspNetCore, then the problem can be caused by calling `UseNLog` together with `AddNLog` or `ConfigureNLog`.

You should only use `UseNLog` together with `NLog.Web.LogBuilder.ConfigureNLog` (Stop using `AddNLog`):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#4-update-programcs

Comment: This was the case for me.

Comment: Note: AddNLog is for ASP.NET Core 1 and UseNLog for ASP.NET Core 2 + 3

Comment: The first part of this is the answer, however there are circumstances that UseNLog shouldn't be used, like when you have a custom implementation of Microsoft ILogger (and you use NLog behind the scene). In that scenario, you would be adding your custom logging provider through loggerFactory.AddProvider in the Asp.Net core pipeline

Comment: @MahdiK.Actually think the answer has become obsolete after these pull-requests have been implemented: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/459 + https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/pull/485 (Released with NLog.Web.AspNetCore ver. 4.9)

Answer (score 1):

This is seems to be because of rule in config file, just change writeTo for each logger, in my case I was able to reolve this issue by following same steps:

**Example:**

Earlier config file which was having issue:

```
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="console" />
</rules>
```

Corrected config file:

```
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="console1" />
</rules>
```

Comment: Please note that there is only one rule in my config file

Answer (score 0):

NLog Logger-method `Error<T>(T value)` is shorthand for `Error("{0}", value)`.

This means the `${message}` output becomes `string.Format("{0}", value)` or `value.ToString()`, which is the original behavior.

NLog have over time tried to improve the handling of `Exception`-object as value:

- NLog 4.1 - [Assign NLog LogEventInfo.Exception so ${exception} works](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/788)
- NLog 4.5.4 - [Assign NLog LogEventInfo.Exception so ${exception} works in more cases](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2586)
- NLog 4.6 - [Changed ${message:withException=true} to only output exception once](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2978)
- NLog 5.0 - [Changed ${message} to only output ex.GetType() + ex.Message](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3684) - Instead of Exception.ToString()
- NLog 5.0 - [Changed default Target Layout to use ${mesage:withException=true}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3637) - Instead of ${message}

But yes a workaround is calling  `Logger.Error(ex, "")`, then `${message}` will output empty-string `""`.

Alternative with NLog v4.6 (and newer) then one can use `${message:withException=true}` instead of `${message} ${exception:format=tostring}`